# How to save values from serial port in Qt,into the computer and print the graph of it when required?

Tags: qt4

Now I have plotted the graph of the values received from serial port in Qt. Now i want to save these values in computer and replot the graph when required and print it. how to do it?

Comment: Store data in a file? What did you tried so far?

Comment: I dont know how to sotre the data into the file,can you please suggest me a sample code.

Comment: I can suggest you to look into Qt docs: QFile, QDataStream, QTextStream